# Get EnvDTE.DTE inside t4 template when TextTransform.exe is run manually

Tags: c#, t4, envdte

The `tt` template contains following code:

```
    var visualStudio 
        = (this.Host as IServiceProvider)
        .GetService(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE)) as EnvDTE.DTE;
```

Editing *tt* from *Visual Studio* triggers code generation. In this case, the `visualStudio` variable is not *null*.

However, `visualStudio` variable is *null*, when same *tt* is run manually via calling `TextTransform.exe` from command line.

Is it possible to obtain `EnvDTE.DTE` when `TextTransform.exe` is run manually? If so, how is it possible to do that?

Comment: you can search or activate a host and use that instance as host of the template: https://www.viva64.com/en/b/0169/

Answer (score 0):

EnvDTE only works from within Visual Studio...